# Why I can not start proxy service? Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose-proxy.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - static_data:/vol/web

    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=app
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=supersecretpassword
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1

    depends_on:
      - db

  proxy:
    image : proxy:latest    
    depends_on:
      - app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:    
      - static_data:/vol/static_data


  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=app
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword

volumes:
  static_data:
```

I checked the port before I run my command

```
netstat -ltnp | grep ':8000'
```

and port was not occupied.
when I go for

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-proxy.yml up
```

I got error

```
ERROR: for 9bac48e03668_recipe-app-api-devops_proxy_1  Cannot start service proxy: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint recipe-app-api-devops_proxy_1 (af5860c135cb37026dcac6ce27151cd4e8448eaddc542d50dcd009c0e24c09fa): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated
```

Why? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Because `8000` is already used on your `app` container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified port `8000` at

```
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Since this port is already used for something, you get the error that it's already allocated. So, you will need to find out what is using port `8000` and either change the port of your container, stop the other process, or change the other process's port.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to bind host port 8000 to two different things:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  proxy:
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

So this tells Compose to try to route host port 8000 to the `app` container, and also to route host port 8000 to the `proxy` container, and it can't do both.  That's essentially the error you're getting.

If you want all requests to your system to go through the `proxy` container, you can just delete the `ports:` block from the `app` container.  It will still be visible from other containers in the same Compose file via `http://app:8000` but it won't be reachable from outside Docker.

If you need both containers to be accessible, you need to change the first `ports:` number, but not the second, on one or the other of the containers.

```yaml
ports:
  - '8001:8000' # host port 8001 -> container port 8000
```

This won't affect connections between containers at all; regardless of what `ports:` are or aren't present, they will always use the "standard" port number for the container they're trying to connect to.

Comment: I get it ,I did now exactly this and it work fine.I need both containers accessible.